# GXT 2 Grid: Vertical Alignment

Tags: grid, gxt

I'm trying to set vertical alignment of the text inside the grid to middle with css:

```
.myGrid .x-grid3-cell {
    vertical-alignment: middle !important;
}
```

but it doesn't work! I already tried with other properties, like row, body, inner, etc. What can I do?

Comment: I will suggest you to move to `GXT 3.x`. Sencha has resolved several issues, a lot of features are introduced and almost all the user have migrated to GXT 3. Sencha will stop providing support for `GXT 2` very soon

Comment: @Vivek Unfortunately in my project we have to use GXT 2. At least for now.

Answer (score 0):

You may try this if this is available in GXT 2 -

```
 ----- Options
HasVerticalAlignment.ALIGN_TOP
HasVerticalAlignment.ALIGN_MIDDLE
HasVerticalAlignment.ALIGN_BOTTOM

--- implementation 

ColumnConfig<StateTestModel, String> column = 
new ColumnConfig<StateTestModel, String>(gridProperties.name(), 150, "Name");
column.setVerticalAlignment(HasVerticalAlignment.ALIGN_MIDDLE);
```

Comment: the .setVerticalAligment is not avaliable :/